# Where should DTO conversion be done in MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dto

Where should DTO conversion be done in MVC?

I am using JPA.
Receive DTO as parameter from Controller.

At this time, is it necessary to convert it in the controller and pass it to the service?

Or, I wonder if the service receives the DTO and converts it.

Comment: Perform all the business logics and transformation in service class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which layer should be used for conversion to DTO from Domain Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822938/which-layer-should-be-used-for-conversion-to-dto-from-domain-object)

Answer (score 0):

I use DTO in service layer .
because service must contain business logic .
controller is just a middleware between processing data and show the result to user so It seems reasonable to map DTO to your entity in service